# How can I put a value of a table as the name of another table in SAS Base?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

In sas base I have the following table:

```
Regis   Book    Page

AAA1    book1   127
AAA2    book2   230
BBB1    book1   58
BBB2    book2   300
```

I have to make a new table that row bookx is the name of the column.

```
Regis  book1  book2 
AAA1   127
AAA2          230
BBB1   58    
BBB2          300
```

Thx.

Comment: You mean name of another column, not table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PROC TRANSPOSE for that.

```
proc transpose out=want;
   by regis;
   id book;
   var page;
   run;
```

[image]